# What is the best way to update a List of property to the entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, savechanges

Hi people I have a List as parameter and I want to save the changes
What is the best method in Entity Framework?
Thanks

```js
public static List<ReservationType>
  putReservations(List<ReservationType> reservationList)
{
  //my reservationList are all objects that came from a JSON
  SaveChanges();  //???
}
```

Comment: you have to iterate through the list to change the state of the entries.And the call to `SaveChanges` once.

Comment: is there a shortcut that doesnt need iteration , my list can have 1 or more array of values . i found this  hoteldb.Entry(reservationList).State = EntityState.Modified;
            hoteldb.SaveChanges(); //what is this for?

Comment: [look at this](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/documentation)